# Index.Mobile.cshtml loading on iOS but not Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a mobile site in ASP.NET MVC4 that will display different views for desktop and mobile devices. For testing purposes I have created a new project in VS2010 and added a Index.Mobile.cshtml view.

This View loads on all the iOS devices, whilst the normal Index.cshtml loads on desktops, as expected. The problem comes from Android devices which will not load the mobile version automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found simple solution:

Controller:

```
string userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
if(userAgent.Contains("Android") || userAgent.Contains("iPad"))
{
   return View("~/Views/Index.Mobile.cshtml");
}
else
{
   return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");
}
```